# Run application in iOS app?

Tags: ios, networking

Is it possible to compile application like Stunnel with libssl into iOS app, when app launch, it runs Stunnel with a conf parameters? Stunnel will open a TCP port.

Comment: Seems unlikely, and even if it does your app will most likely be rejected from the app store

Comment: I don't need to submit it to app store :)

Comment: You might want to check around the jailbreak forums then, compiling another application inside of an app isn't at all conventional.

Comment: If jailbroken, it should be more easy to run it without an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it exactly as you have stated it because iOS will not allow to fork a process. 
But what you can do is rename the `main` procedure of Stunnel to something like `stunnel_main`, compile the sources of stunnel into your app (by adding the relevant source files to your project). When your app starts executing, create a new thread that calls `stunnel_main` with whatever parameters you want.

It's not pretty, but it will work.

Comment: I spent a couple days trying to do exactly this, and I am now giving up and saying it can not be (easily) done. The problem is that there are too many compilation errors in xcode from the stunnel source files. Even if you were to spend weeks fixing these errors and get it to compile, it will still be a mystery whether the compiled stunnel will work correctly.